# SQL enforce value of a column if other column is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm having a hard time to explain this so let me illustrate it with an exemple.

I have a table for comments and it looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT UNSIGNED,
    article_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    submitted_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    comment TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_com_parent
        FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES comments (id)
    CONSTRAINT fk_com_article
        FOREIGN KEY (article_id)
        REFERENCES articles (id)
    CONSTRAINT fk_com_user
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Now it makes sense that if `parent_id` is set, child and parent should share the same `article_id`.

Answers to a comment **must** be on the same article. So is there a way to contraint this?

Comment: probably could be done with triggers. Is it necessary to duplicate. recursive CTEs (MySQL-8.0/MariaDB-10.2) mean these are derivable in a query.

Comment: *if parent_id is set, child and parent should share the same article_id.* Specify the field you means child. *Answers to a comment must be on the same article. So is there a way to contraint this?* If so the logic must be that the record have `arcticle_id` IS NULL when `parent_id` IS NOT NULL. And the article ID must be obtained from its parent for that record.

Comment: @akina That could do. How could I enforce that?

Comment: @danblack, I'm going to give a look at triggers then, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Answers to a comment must be on the same article. So is there a way to contraint this?

If so the logic must be that the record have arcticle_id IS NULL when parent_id IS NOT NULL. And the article ID must be obtained from its parent for that record.

```
SELECT ... , 
       CASE WHEN t1.parent_id IS NULL 
            THEN t1.article_id 
            ELSE t2.article_id 
       END article_id, 
       ...
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
    ON t2.user_id = t1.parent_id
...
```

So if `parent_id` is set, the `article_id` is taken from parent's record, and the value from current record is simply ignored.